# How to make image responsive in flexbox with set width?

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, flexbox

I have pics that have different width and height, but I want to make them cover fit in the item flexbox, how can I do that?

```css
.item-here img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.section-grid {
  max-width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item-here {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-grid" id="list-product">
  <div class="item-here">
    <img class="" src="https://www.lindemans.com/-/media/Images/Lindemans2016/Wine-Bottleshots/Bin-Series/New-Bin-Bromley/Lindemans-Chardonnay-Bin-65-BS.ashx?la=en&sc=1&modified=20190521001727&mw=1382&hash=AE8135A39D9B975147D12D1382ABD0926A327983">
  </div>

  <div class="item-here">
    <img class="" src="https://www.lindemans.com/-/media/Images/Lindemans2016/Wine-Bottleshots/Bin-Series/New-Bin-Bromley/Lindemans-Chardonnay-Bin-65-BS.ashx?la=en&sc=1&modified=20190521001727&mw=1382&hash=AE8135A39D9B975147D12D1382ABD0926A327983">
  </div>
</div>
```

i want to make this box responsive so when in mobile it must be wrap

[image: my flex image here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change image setting to => `object-fit: contain` (not cover in your case):

> **contain** The replaced content is scaled to maintain its aspect ratio while fitting within the element’s content box.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

```css
.item-here img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.item-here {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.section-grid {
  max-width: 1200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-grid" id="list-product">
  <div class="item-here">
    <img class="" src="https://www.lindemans.com/-/media/Images/Lindemans2016/Wine-Bottleshots/Bin-Series/New-Bin-Bromley/Lindemans-Chardonnay-Bin-65-BS.ashx?la=en&sc=1&modified=20190521001727&mw=1382&hash=AE8135A39D9B975147D12D1382ABD0926A327983">
  </div>

  <div class="item-here">
    <img class="" src="https://www.lindemans.com/-/media/Images/Lindemans2016/Wine-Bottleshots/Bin-Series/New-Bin-Bromley/Lindemans-Chardonnay-Bin-65-BS.ashx?la=en&sc=1&modified=20190521001727&mw=1382&hash=AE8135A39D9B975147D12D1382ABD0926A327983">
  </div>
</div>
```

VS `object-fit: cover` (Your code):

> **cover** The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while filling the element’s entire content box. If the object's aspect
>   ratio does not match the aspect ratio of its box, then the object will
>   be clipped to fit. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

[image]

** In general, it's not the best idea to give fixed height to content cols on a responsive site (Could cause to overflow-y issues).